# @ModelAttribute is returning something wrong

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I'm building an application that has these methods in the Controller for a form handling:

```
//This will prepare the model and populate the form
@RequestMapping(value="verbete",method = RequestMethod.GET, params="new")
public String addVerbete(@ModelAttribute("verbeteform") VerbeteForm verbeteForm,
    Map<String, Object> model){
  verbeteForm.getNomes().add(new NomesVerbete());
  // add one significado
  verbeteForm.getSignificados().add(new SignificadosVerbete());
  // depois de implementar o Security
  verbeteForm.getVerbete().setAutor(usuarioService.buscarUsuarioPorLogin("greati"));
  // seta a data  
  verbeteForm.getVerbete().setDataLancamento(new Date());        
  // popula categorias
  verbeteForm.setCategorias(verbeteService.listarCategorias());

  return "editorVerbete";
}
@RequestMapping(value="verbete", params="new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addVerbeteFromForm(@ModelAttribute("verbeteform") VerbeteForm verbeteForm,
    Map<String, Object> model){

  Verbete verbete = verbeteForm.getVerbete();      

  List<NomesVerbete> nomes = verbeteForm.getNomes();
  List<SignificadosVerbete> significados = verbeteForm.getSignificados();

  long idVerbeteSalvo = verbeteService.addVerbete(verbete);
  Verbete verbeteSalvo = verbeteService.getVerbetePorId(idVerbeteSalvo);

  for(NomesVerbete nome:nomes){
    nome.setVerbete(verbeteSalvo);
    verbeteService.addNomesVerbete(nome);
  }
  for(SignificadosVerbete significado:significados){
    significado.setVerbete(verbeteSalvo);
    significado.setCategoria(verbeteService.getCategoriaPorNome(significado.getCategoria().getNome()));
    verbeteService.addSignificadosVerbete(significado);
  }
  return "editorVerbete";
}
```

So, I was expecting that the date and the author would be setted in the model, but, when I submit the form, it says that the attributes `dataLancamento` (it's a date) and `autor` are not in the model, throwing an error because they cannot be null in the database.

Maybe I didn't understand how `@ModelAttribute` works, or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

A solution would be set the `dataLancamento` and `autor` in the second method, but I don't know if it's right. So, could you show me a way?

(Some words are in Portuguese... Please, tell me if it's a problem.)

Answer (score 0):

When the first method is execute and the form is rendered the first time, the autor should be in the model. So using ${verbeteform.autor} should print the autor field.

But when you submit the form, the model is fullfilled with the data in the form. So if the form doesnt have a autor field like:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="verbeteform" method="POST">
<form:input path="autor"/>
</form:form>
```

the value is not added to the model, so in the second controller you have a null value in the autor field because the model is regenerated.

Comment: Hum, interesting. So, in order to update an object, if I have a path like user/edit?id=32, when I submit the form, I need to use this parameter (id), in the controller, to get the object and set the attributes that I want to update, right?

Comment: If you want to update something it is better (at least it is my opinion) to put that in the form. If you dont want that a particular field appear in the form you can use the form:hidden tag.